# Sending cookies from C# Application to an Internet Explorer pop-up window

Tags: c#, browser, cookies, webforms

I have a C# application that has links to certain features on a web application that uses the same login credentials.  If the user has logged in using the application and they click a link, a new browser window opens (usually IE but may be just the default browser) and asks the them to authenticate again.

Is there a way to make the account stay logged in whether it is in the C# application or in a separate browser window? The web application uses cookies to store the users session variables for authentication, the C# application has the same session info but not in a cookie.

Essentially I need to create a cookie from the C# application's session information and pass it to the new browser window.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "C# form" and how it is different from a normal browser window.

Comment: Do you mean you have a Windows application that allows you to browse a Website?

Comment: I guess my answer became meaningless after you clarified that you are launching the window from a Windows form. Deleted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe any new window instance will start a new session and therefore wipe out any session cookies you may have created prior to opening a new browser through either `Process.Start("iexplorer.exe", "www.msn.ca")` or `webBrowser1.Navigate("www.msn.ca", true)`.

However I finally found a work around for this problem. It involves the following:

1. Create your own web browser that looks almost exactly like Internet Explorer. See the folowing link for code for a basic browser and customize it as needed.

   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379558(VS.80).aspx

   I fixed the bug by replacing the obsolete RaftingStrip with the ToolStrip, ToolStripContainer. (Email me if you want this debugged code. I'd post it but I think it's too long for this forum.)

   For myself, I added

   1. constructor to pass the target url, set it to the Address bar, set it as the home page and also pass the security token
   2. properties to enable/disable the Address bar and Search bars
   3. added Cut, Copy, Paste, SaveAs, and Print buttons
   4. changed the progress icon from "C#" to an hourglass
2. On the web browser form's declaration section, add

   ```
   DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
   public static extern bool InternetSetCookie(string lpszUrlName,
            string lbszCookieName, string lpszCookieData);
   ```
3. On the web browser form load and Create_a_new_tab(), before the webpage.Navigate() insert the lines below that save the token to a session cookie. (This may also be required on the button_go_click and button_search_click events if navigating to a new domain.  Personally, I would disable the Address and Search bars if passing a security token.)

   ```
   string url = comboBox_url.Text.Trim();  // write the session cookie
   string security_token = "my_session_id=12345" // should have been passed to constructor
   InternetSetCookie(url, null, security_token);
   ```

The user will never know the difference and you have control over what features to turn on/off or implement.

Comment: Definitely not an easy solution, but thanks for the answer!  We decided a long time ago to just let the user login again, but it's good to know what needs to be if we ever decide otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I've only been able to do this for an embedded WebBrowser control (see code below) but NOT for new IE window. Still haven't found an answer.

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool InternetSetCookie(string lpszUrlName, string lbszCookieName, string lpszCookieData);

string url = "http://www.google.com";

// write the session cookie
InternetSetCookie(url, null, "abc=1");

webBrowser1.Navigate(url);
```

Comment: It seems there isn't a way to persist sessions from a C# application to an IE window.

Comment: You need to set the expiry time of the cookie in order to open it in new IE window. For example:           
 InternetSetCookie("https://example.com", cookieName, cookieValue + ";expires=Sat, 10-Oct-2018 00:00:00 GMT");

Answer (score -1):

You can use the usual session mode.

e.g:

```
Session.Add("<sessionName>", <variable which contains the session data>>
```

If you want to hold the username which is in a variable called "User", you can use the below code:

```
Session.Add("UserName", User);
```

In order to validate this session in your webpage, use the below code under the page_lad method.

```
if(Session["UserName"] != null)
{
   ********
}
else
{
   ******* (you can redirect to your home page...)
}
```