# how the browser's password management works?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, google-chrome, web

I am curious to know how the password management works in browsers (IE/Chrome).

E.g: I login into my gmail account. now I open a new tab in the same browser and enter the same url (gmail url) then it does not ask for the user name and password. Means it reads the username and password from session or cookies or somewhere else.

How can we read this data (username and password) using a c# program?

Thanks in advance.
Umang

Comment: That is true - when you log in, server saves your authentication information. This may be cookies, session, even the url or anywhere else - depends on server. You should add up more details so that we could help you

Comment: I have given the complete scenario. I want to get the username and password which are stored into the browser session/cookies or wherever this information is stored.

Answer (score 0):

The data is stored in the browser's internal database. As a security feature, you cannot easily read this data using .NET technologies. Otherwise malware would have a field day with it!

**EDIT**: It seems that recent IE versions store the data in the registry, encrypted with the often-unset account password:
http://www.howtogeek.com/68231/how-secure-are-your-saved-internet-explorer-passwords/

Comment: This is misleading, he is not asking about save password feature

Comment: the data may not be in browser at all - when authentication is saved into session. It's incorrect to say that data is stored in browsers internal database. And once again, your link points to save password feature - he is not asking about that :)

Comment: yes, I am not asking about save password feature. My question is totally different.
But I believe this can be done using a c# program.

Comment: Sorry, rereading the post I see what you are getting at. You can reuse IE's cookies from .NET I believe, not not Firefox or Opera cookies. I'll dig up some info, one minute.

Comment: Sorry, you [cannot persist a session from IE to your C# app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/976907/sending-cookies-from-c-sharp-application-to-an-internet-explorer-pop-up-window). Read the rest of that thread, there seems to be much pertinent information to your application there. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the given link does not answer to my question. Even if I open a new window of the same browser, it does not ask for the username and password. It means information is stored somewhere and it reads the same from there. So I believe we can read that information from C# application.

Comment: The cookies are encrypted, and each session encrypts them differently. Like I said, it is a security feature of the browser. The best that you can do is to open a new window of that browser.

Answer (score 0):

### **Passwords**

The simplest and the oldest method of entity authentication is the password, something that the claimant possesses. A password is used when a user needs to access a system to use the system's resources (log-in). Each user has a user identification that is public and a password that is private. We can divide this authentication scheme into two separate groups: the fixed password and the one-time password.

#### **Fixed Password**

In this group, the password is fixed; the same password is used over and over for every
access. This approach is subject to several attacks.

###### **o Eavesdropping.**

Eve can watch Alice when she types her password. Most systems, as a security measure, do not show the characters a user types. Eavesdropping can take a more sophisticated form. Eve can listen to the line and then intercept the message, thereby capturing the password for her own use.

###### **o Stealing a Password.**

The second type of attack occurs when Eve tries to physically steal Alice's password. This can be prevented if Alice does not write down the
password; instead, she just commits it to memory. Therefore, a password should be very simple or else related to something familiar to Alice, which makes the password vulnerable to other types of attacks.

###### **o Accessing a file.**

Eve can hack into the system and get access to the file where the
passwords are stored. Eve can read the file and find Alice's password or even
change it. To prevent this type of attack, the file can be read/write protected. However, most systems need this type of file to be readable by the public.

###### **o Guessing.**

Eve can log into the system and try to guess Alice's password by trying
different combinations of characters. The password is particularly vulnerable if the user is allowed to choose a short password (a few characters). It is also vulnerable if Alice has chosen something unimaginative, such as her birthday, her child's name, or the name of her favorite actor. To prevent guessing, a long random password is recommended, something that is not very obvious. However, the use of such a random password may also create a problem; Alice might store the password somewhere so as not to forget it. This makes the password subject to stealing.

A more secure approach is to store the hash of the password in the password file (instead of the plaintext password). Any user can read the contents of the file, but, because the hash function is a one-way function, it is almost impossible to guess the value of the password. The hash function prevents Eve from gaining access to the system even though she has the password file. However, there is a possibility of another type of attack called the dictionary attack. In this attack, Eve is interested in finding one pass-
word, regardless of the user ID. For example, if the password is 6 digits, Eve can create a list of 6-digit numbers (000000 to 999999), and then apply the hash function to every number; the result is a list of 1 million hashes. She can then get the password file and search the second-column entries to find a match. This could be programmed and run offline on Eve's private computer. After a match is found, Eve can go online and use the
password to access the system. We will see how to make this attack more difficult in the third approach.

Another approach is called salting the password. When the password string is created, a random string, called the salt, is concatenated to the password. The salted password is then hashed. The rD, salt, and the hash are then stored in the file. Now, when a user asks for access, the system extracts the salt, concatenates it with the received password, makes a hash out of the result, and compares it with the hash stored in the file. If there is a match, access
is granted, otherwise, it is denied. Salting makes the dictionary attack more difficult. If the original password is 6 digits and the salt is 4 digits, then hashing is done over a 10-digit value. This means that Eve now needs to make a list of 10 million items and create a hash for each of them. The list of hashes has 10 million entries and the comparison takes much longer. Salting is very effective if the salt is a very long random number. The UNIX operating system uses a variation of this method.

In another approach, two identification techniques are combined. A good example of this type of authentication is the use of an ATM card with a PIN (personal identification number). The card belongs to the category "something possessed" and the PIN belongs to the category "something known." The PIN is actually a password that enhances the security of the card. If the card is stolen, it cannot be used unless the PIN is known. The PIN, however, is traditionally very short so it is easily remembered by the owner. This makes it vulnerable to the guessing type of attack.

Source: Data Communications and Networking By Behrouz A.Forouzan